# gitlab-ci: Terraform has no command named "sh". Did you mean "show"

Tags: terraform, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to set up Terrafom validation on Gitlab CI.
However a build fails with an error: "Terraform has no command named "sh". Did you mean "show"?"

Why does it happen? How could it be fixed?

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: hashicorp/terraform:light

before_script:
  - terraform init

validate:
  script:
    - terraform validate
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to override the entrypoint in the terraform image so you have access to the shell.

```
image: 
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint: [""]

before_script:
  - terraform init

validate:
  script:
    - terraform validate
```

You can also take a look at the official gitlab [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/) how to integrate terraform with gitlab, as the have a template for that.

Comment: Looks like Gitlab Terraform integration is not an option for me.
Currently I want to validate tf file only. But Gitlab runs `plan` and `apply` too (see [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/infrastructure/#quick-start)).  
Is there any way to turn off Gitlab's `plan` and `apply`?

Comment: If gitlab terraform is no option for you just try to overwrite the entrypoint for your image as posted above, this should fix your problem